# Subject-matter of x, subject of x, object of x

Tags: grammar, nouns, subjects, objects, philosophy

Please help me understand the difference in meaning an nuance between the following phrases:

1. Subject-matter of x (e.g. subject-matter of a book)
2. Subject of x (e.g. subject of a discussion)
3. Object of x (e.g. object of a study)

It seems to me that in all three cases, the phrase indicates something to the effect of "what x is about." How should I understand the differences between them?

Answer (score 0):

Here are the Merriam-Webster definitions and Subject, while having more uses than Subject Matter, does seem to be a synonym. (see the definition example below)

All of this could have been answered by a quick dictionary search.

*Object 4 : a thing that forms an element of or constitutes the subject matter of an investigation or science objects of study*

*subject matter: matter presented for consideration in discussion, thought, or study*

*subject 3 d (1) : **something concerning which something is said or done the subject of the essay** (2) : something represented or indicated in a work of art
e (1) : the term of a logical proposition that denotes the entity of which something is affirmed or denied; also : the entity denoted (2) : a word or word group denoting that of which something is predicated*